# Php array preset value insertation

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Hi i have following array from a result:

```
$ouput = $OuputTypeDB->getTotalOutput($uid);
```

There is five type of output each with it own value, the current result return as follow:

```
Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 4
                    [val] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 3
                    [val] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 2
                    [val] => 1
                )

        )
```

The output result are shown based on type desc order, now the problems is there is no type for 5 and 1, how can i add array for 5 and 1 on above result and sort it in following way:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 5
            [count] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 4
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 3
            [count] => 1
        )

   [3] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 2
            [count] => 1
        )

   [4] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 1
            [count] => 0
        )

)
```

Since there is no value for type 5 and 1 both are set with `val 0`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307676/set-default-to-php-array/15307780) less then 20 hours ago

here is the answer:

```
foreach ($output as $arr) {
    $vote[$arr['type']] = $arr['val'];
}
$output = array();
for ($i=5; $i>0; $i--) {
    $output[] = array("rating"=>$i,"count"=> $vote[$i] ? $vote[$i] : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for add an item do
$output[] = array("rating"=>5, "count"=>$countFor5);
for sorting you can use the uksort or usort function

Comment: No, this had to do checking from $output result and add type which is not already there with default val of 0